# Lua - Saving data to array in for loop

Tags: arrays, lua, computercraft

in my lua program, I want to check the sides for a redstone input (using a for loop to check).
the last few lines are ment to print out ther result of the array, as a debug tool. the output is the side name followed by 0 (a true/false is expected). the data will be used later in the program.

thank you.

http://www.pastebin.com/0innMjcP

```
function array()
  a = {}
  for i=1, 6 do
    a[i] = {}

    for j=1, 2 do
      a[i][j] = 0
    end
  end
  a[1][1]= "front"
  a[2][1]= "back"
  a[3][1]= "left"
  a[4][1]= "right"
  a[5][1]= "top"
  a[6][1]= "bottom"
end

array()

for i=1, 6 do
  input=redstone.getInput(a[i][1])
  if input=="true" then
    a[2][2]="true"

  elseif input=="false" then
    a[3][2]="false"
  end
end
for i=1, 6 do
  print(a[i][1])
  print(a[i][2])
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [manual of `redstone.getInput()`](http://computercraft.info/wiki/index.php?title=Redstone.getInput), it returns a boolean, not a string, so this line

```
if input == "true" then
```

should be

```
if input == true then
```

The same for the `elseif` part.